# Table view not reloading the data

Tags: xcode, tableview

Hi am trying to input a NSMutable array and display it in a table view. Initially the array is nil. The table view is called from another view controller and data is in a singleton. Am using a third class to enter additional array elements. Eerything is working fine except when I hit the back button from third class, instead of string values, cells appear to be black in the table view. Once I click a particular cell, the value shows up. If I deselect it, the cell again turns black.
Will really appreciate if someone can help me
my table class is

```
@implementation stocktable

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

-(void)insertaobject{

    stockname *s1 = [[stockname alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:s1 animated:YES];
    [s1 release];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];


 UIBarButtonItem *addbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertaobject)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addbutton;
 [addbutton release];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector: @selector(addthestocks:) name:@"someevent" object: nil];

}


-(void)addthestocks:(NSNotification*)notification{

    if ([[notification name]isEqualToString:@"someevent"]) {
        //[self.navigationController.visibleViewController reloadInputViews];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[[stockdata sharedarray] stocksymbols]count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[[stockdata sharedarray] stocksymbols] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[self.thedatamodel.stocksymbols objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

and third class is

```
@implementation stockname

@synthesize txt1;
@synthesize label2;
@synthesize button1;


-(IBAction)textfieldoneediting:(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    label2.text = txt1.text;
    NSString* stkk = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:txt1.text];
    [[[stockdata sharedarray]stocksymbols] addObject:stkk];
    if ([[[stockdata sharedarray]stocksymbols]count]>0) {
        NSLog(@",,%@",[[[stockdata sharedarray]stocksymbols]objectAtIndex:0]);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"someevent" object: self];

}

-(IBAction)startediting:(id)sender{

    [sender becomeFirstResponder];



}
```

Comment: If you are registering for an event in `viewWillAppear` then unregister it in `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: am not sure if I understand this...what are you asking me to unregister